# Collecting and transmitting images from Raspberry Pi Pico (adequacy of SPI communication)

Tags: ros2, opencv

I did:
Currently, it takes about 7 seconds with Arduino to create an image of about 50kB, 1280x960 JPEG image through SPI communication.

Next goal: shorten time

To shorten this, we decided to use Pico (only used as a controller).

At the same time, there is a question that arises.

1. Is SPI communication the fastest method other than Wi-Fi or Bluetooth?
2. I use SPI as a controller, but we do not plan to use serial communication (to use a high baud rate). So, I want to connect both the upper and lower units via SPI. Will there be adequate communication? (Example: PI4 <-> PICO <-> camera, all exist on the same spi connection)
3. If I do this, will I be able to connect at 1,000,000 bps?

- Is there anything related to spi communication between using this as micro ros and using it as a controller?

Add) Now,I have ordered the pico wh model.

Add)) I think I will choose to transfer photos by connecting pico to pi4 via usb.
In the case of the motor, I need to check whether it can be controlled through pi4 or pico.
(In the case of micro-ros, I know that SPI operates normally, but when connecting a motor, I do not know the concept of asynchronous parts, whether it is possible to control the motor while processing the image, so I need to study  .)

(If you use Pico like Arduino, spi control is possible. We will check whether the message delivery process works well during the message delivery process.)